# Toast not getting displayed in AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, toast

The question is simple. Actually When I try to  toast message, It is not getting displayed. Could you please guide me to resolve this.

```
  protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            if (result.equals("200")) {
              Toast.makeText(CallArduino,appliance + " Success ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();    
          }else { 

                Toast.makeText(CallArduino, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();      
          } 


    return "success";
  }
```

Comment: As the answers say, you should make a toast in the UI thread. It also might help if the doInBackground method returned a boolean so postExecute() can choose what toast to make.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Toast` can't be shown in background thread you should call it within the UI thread, in `onPostExecute()` for example

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to do a UI operation on a background thread, which is forbidden.

Any UI operation (including displaying a toast) must be done in the UI thread.

You could for instance display your toast in the `onPostExecute` method:

```
protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
    // do your background stuff
} 

protected void onPostExecute (Result result) {
    if (result.equals("200")) {
        Toast.makeText(CallArduino,appliance + " Success ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();    
    }else { 

        Toast.makeText(CallArduino, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();      
    } 
}
```

Comment: 2-08 12:28:42.909: E/AndroidRuntime(4342): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-08 12:28:42.909: E/AndroidRuntime(4342):  at com.example.homeautomation.CallArduino$httpTask.onPostExecute(CallArduino.java:121)
12-08 12:28:42.909: E/AndroidRuntime(4342):  at com.example.homeautomation.CallArduino$httpTask.onPostExecute(CallArduino.java:1)
12-08 12:28:42.909: E/AndroidRuntime(4342):  at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:602)
12-08 12:28:42.909: E/AndroidRuntime(4342):  at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:156)